# JQuery как загрузить картинку перетаскиванием на сайт?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Как загрузить картинку перетаскиванием на сайт? без формы(input)?
Есть некая область для перетаскивания картинки, после drag'n dropa картинка должна появится на другой области с помощью AJAX

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий пример, сделал в одном файле для наглядности

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $("#drop-area").on('dragenter', function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).css('background', '#BBD5B8');
 });

 $("#drop-area").on('dragover', function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
 });

 $("#drop-area").on('drop', function (e){
  $(this).css('background', '#D8F9D3');
  e.preventDefault();
  var image = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
  createFormData(image);
 });
});

function createFormData(image)
{
 var formImage = new FormData();
 formImage.append('userImage', image[0]);
 uploadFormData(formImage);
}

function uploadFormData(formData) 
{
 $.ajax({
 url: "index.php",
 type: "POST",
 data: formData,
 contentType:false,
 cache: false,
 processData: false,
 success: function(data){
  $('#drop-area').html(data);
 }});
}
</script>

<style>
body
{
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0px;
 font-family:helvetica;
 background-color:#084B8A;
}
#wrapper
{
 text-align:center;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0px;
 width:995px;
}
#drop-area
{
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-left:220px;
 width:550px;
 height:200px;
 background-color:white;
 border:3px dashed grey;
}
.drop-text
{
 margin-top:70px;
 color:grey;
 font-size:25px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
#drop-area img
{
 max-width:200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['userImage'])) 
{
 if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
  $sourcePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
  $targetPath = "images/".$_FILES['userImage']['name'];
  if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
  ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $targetPath; ?>">
   <?php
   exit();
  }
 }
}
?>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="drop-area">
  <h3 class="drop-text">Drag and Drop Images Here</h3>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: MLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/OpenServer/domains/webapplication/index.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery.min.js:4

Comment: я так понял это из за того что я на локалке проверяю?

Comment: у меня на локалке все бежит

Comment: У вас должен быть локальный сервер xampp к примеру. Фаил должен быть с расширением PHP. Так будет работать , сделайте все как я написал

Comment: openserver стоит, файл разумеется .php)